# Show result below custom form in drupal 8

Tags: search, drupal, drupal-8

I have created custom form from form API and I want to fetch records from DB and display below form after submit.

I have tried few reference with no success. Here is my code

```
 public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)     {
   $terms = db_query("select name from taxonomy_term_field_data where vid =   'category'");
$termsData = $terms->fetchAll();
$form_state->setRebuild();
$form_state->setStorage= $termsData;
$output = '';
foreach($termsData as $d){
    $output .= $d->name;
}
$form_state->setStorage= $output;
 return $output;
}
```

any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `db_select` use the following snippet

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $db = \Drupal::database();
    $terms = $db->select('taxonomy_term_field_data','tfd')->fields('tfd')->condition('vid','category')->execute();

    $termsData = $terms->fetchAll();
    $form_state->setRebuild();
    $form_state->setStorage= $termsData;
    $output = '';
    foreach($termsData as $d){
        $output .= $d->name;
    }
    $form_state->setStorage= $output;
     return $output;
}
```

but I suggest do it by Entity API.for more information taking a look on [Drupal Entity API on Drupal 8](https://www.yuseferi.com/en/blog/everything-entity-or-entity-everything-drupal-8) and **[Drupal Entity Cheat Sheet](https://www.yuseferi.com/en/blog/Drupal-entity-API-cheat-sheet)**

let me know if it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Hello Yusef, given links are not working. please share again. Thanks

Comment: @SanjPrajapati https://www.yuseferi.com/en/blog/Drupal-entity-API-cheat-sheet

have tried my solution? 
I'm here to help you. no worries.